# How to iterate over PyTorch tensor

Tags: pytorch, iteration, tensor

I have a tensor data of size (1000,110) and I want to iterate over the first index of the tensor and calculate the following.

```
    data = torch.randn(size=(1000,110)).to(device)
    
    male_poor = torch.tensor(0).float().to(device)
    male_rich = torch.tensor(0).float().to(device)
    
    female_poor = torch.tensor(0).float().to(device)
    female_rich = torch.tensor(0).float().to(device)
    
    for i in data:
    
        if torch.argmax(i[64:66]) == 0 and torch.argmax(i[108:110]) == 0:
          female_poor += 1
        if torch.argmax(i[64:66]) == 0 and torch.argmax(i[108:110]) == 1:
          female_rich += 1
        if torch.argmax(i[64:66]) == 1 and torch.argmax(i[108:110]) == 0:
          male_poor += 1
        if torch.argmax(i[64:66]) == 1 and torch.argmax(i[108:110]) == 1:
          male_rich += 1


    disparity = ((female_rich/(female_rich + female_poor))) / ((male_rich/(male_rich + male_poor)))
```

Is there a faster way than for loop to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key in pytorch (as well as numpy) is vectorizataion, that is if you can remove loops by operating on matrices it will be a lot faster. Loops in python are quite slow compared to the loops in the underlying compiled C code. On my machine the execution time for your code was about 0.091s, the following vectorized code was about 0.002s so about x50 faster:

```
import torch
torch.manual_seed(0)
device = torch.device('cpu')

data = torch.randn(size=(1000, 110)).to(device)

import time
t = time.time()
#vectorize over first dimension
argmax64_0 = torch.argmax(data[:, 64:66], dim=1) == 0
argmax64_1 = torch.argmax(data[:, 64:66], dim=1) == 1
argmax108_0 = torch.argmax(data[:, 108:110], dim=1) == 0
argmax108_1 = torch.argmax(data[:, 108:110], dim=1) == 1
female_poor = (argmax64_0 & argmax108_0).sum()
female_rich = (argmax64_0 & argmax108_1).sum()
male_poor = (argmax64_1 & argmax108_0).sum()
male_rich = (argmax64_1 & argmax108_1).sum()

disparity = ((female_rich / (female_rich + female_poor))) / ((male_rich / (male_rich + male_poor)))

print(time.time()-t)
print(disparity)
```

Comment: I didn't see dim argument in argmax documentations, thanks for the help!